# When running Python Flask Server, Jenkins is not successful and continues to load

Tags: python, flask, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline

I am building CICD through Jenkins.
But there are problems.

It is planning to upload source code first and turn on flask server through batch file.
I wrote a shell script for Jenkins' Build>Execute Shell.

```
postCommand=/cygdrive/c/workspace/ContactPortal_Flask/run.bat
sshpass -p ${deployPassword} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${deployUser}@${deployServer} ${postCommand}
```

Here is run.bat file

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\develop\instantclient_12_1;C:\develop\Anaconda3;C:\develop\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\develop\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\develop\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\develop\Anaconda3\Scripts;
set "START=C:\workspace\ContactPortal_Flask\start.bat"
cd C:\workspace\ContactPortal_Flask
python -m flask run
```

then, The source code upload was successful, and turning on the flask server was also successful, but Jenkins was not marked Success and continued to load.

[image]

[image]

please help!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is that `python -m flask run` starts the server and will not finish until user hit Ctrl+C.

Since the target system is on Windows, you may want to create custom service and have jenkin start that service at the end instead. For service creation see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/create-user-defined-service And by starting this service (e.g. with `NET START <service-name>`) jenkin can finish, and flask can start running in the background.

Also for a production system, you may want to consider checking [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/index.html) and pick a proper web server instead of using the builtin web server provided by flask.

Comment: Jenkins was able to start the application using 'nohup python -m flask run', so thanks. Earlier I tried using 'nohup flask run &', but failed.